# How To:remove one character from from one textbox with backspace and it will remove more than one character from other textbox

Tags: vb.net

```
Private Sub txtInput_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As    System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles txtInput.KeyPress

Dim len As Integer

 len = txtCode.Text.Length

If (Asc(e.KeyChar) = 65 Or Asc(e.KeyChar) = 97) Then

        txtCode.Text += "Acer" & " "

    ElseIf (Asc(e.KeyChar) = 66 Or Asc(e.KeyChar) = 98) Then
        txtCode.Text += "King" & " "

    ElseIf (Asc(e.KeyChar) = 8) Then
        Try
            txtCode.Text = txtCode.Text.Remove(len - 4, len)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
     End If

     End Sub
```

i dont have permission to post image so please consider it

i want to delete "b" from first textbox and i should delete "King" from second textbox
the length of each word is same "Acer" "King" it is always 4 in length

but i am getting following error

"Index and count must refer to a location within the string.
Parameter name: count"

i also tried by replacing "len-4" by another variable dim c as integer=len-4

Answer (score 0):

```
textbox2.text = left(textbox2.text,len(textbox2.text)-4)
```

This basically strips the last 4 characters from `textbox2`.

Comment: i renamed my dim len as string to len2 coz len is inbuild function and I Tried your suggetion But it having error on "Left" Error 'Public Property Left() As Integer' has no parameters and its return type cannot be indexed